# unable to download html as excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

By using below javascript  ,I have started to get table tags and  in excel . Earlier it used to work fine.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>', base64 = function(
            s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    }, format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
            return c[p];
        })
    }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType)
            table = document.getElementById(table);
        var cln=table.cloneNode(true);
        var paras = cln.getElementsByClassName('ignore');

        while(paras[0]) {
            paras[0].parentNode.removeChild(paras[0]);
        }
        var ctx = {
            worksheet : name || 'Worksheet',
            table : cln.innerHTML
        }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})();
```

Comment: What does it do now instead of working ?

Comment: It creates excel  fine but it is not filtering html table tags like td and tr as it was used to do. So, now whole html table with mark up is getting written in excel cells and some browsers have stopped even parsing it.